# Checkout cart products disables randomly

Tags: magento2, checkout, addtocart, mini-cart, checkoutsession

I have created a website using Magento 2.2.3.

I'm facing issues with **adding product to the cart**.

The issue is, 
I can add the product to the cart and able to checkout. But, If i want to add some other products to the cart page, the `old product` which i added before in the cart is `disabling`. I suspect that this problem happens because of cache. I'm not sure what i have missed because the console didn't show any error.

Please share your ideas to resolve this issue.